# How to group by data and select first record from each group by datetime and group by again?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table like below :

**JobSchedular:**

```
JobId     ProcessId      DepartmentId         Status         ProcessedTime    
1         100            10                   Done           2022-11-08 19:41
2         101            10                   Done           2022-11-09 19:41
3         100            10                   Failed         2022-11-09 19:41
```

I want to `group by ProcessId and select top 1 Status by latest` `ProcessedTime`(`order by ProcessedTime desc`) and then again group by "`Status`" to calculate "`Done`" and
"`Failed`" statistics.

**Final Output:**

```
Done = 1
Failed = 1
```

Will consider "`Fail`" status for `ProcessId = 100`  based on latest `2022-11-09 19:41`

**Code:**

```
var statistics = (from js in context.JobSchedular
                  where js.DepartmentId == 10
                  group by ProcessId //
                  select new StatisticsModel
                  {
                     Done = 1,
                     Failed = 1
                  }
                  ).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am little confused here with group by ProcessId and select top 1 Status by latest ProcessedTime and then further group by "Status" to calculate statistics.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do it in stages and then refactor if possible. Do the first grouping. That will give you a list of groups. You can then call `Select` on that list and select the first item in each group. You'll then have a list of single items and you can then do the second grouping. You don't have to do everything in one go. Break it down into parts, address each part separately and then simplify if possible.

Comment: @jmcilhinney So it’s not possible to achieve the expected output in 1 final query and send to database?

Comment: It may well be, but you shouldn't necessarily try to do it that way in one go. If you do things in stages then you can concentrate on one thing at a time. Once you have all the stages working separately then you can combine them and you may well end up with a single query. It's too easy to confuse yourself if you try to do too many things at the same time though. Divide and conquer.

Comment: Please show `StatisticsModel` class. Does `Done` and `Failed` are count of statuses or it is just bit value (0 or 1)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Done and Failed are “int” properties  basically count of statuses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I corectly understand expected result it should be the following query:

```cs
var jobs = 
    from js in context.JobSchedular
    where js.DepartmentId == 10
    select js;

var staitsticQuery = 
    from js in jobs
    group js by js.ProcessId into g
    select new 
    {
        ProcessId = g.Key,
        Done = g.Sum(x => x.Status == "Done" ? 1 : 0),
        Failed = g.Sum(x => x.Status == "Failed" ? 1 : 0)
    };

var finalQuery = 
    from s in staitsticQuery
    from js in jobs
        .Where(js => js.ProcessId == s.ProcessId)
        .OrderByDescending(js => js.ProcessedTime)
        .Take(1)
    select new 
    {
        ProcessId = s.ProcessId,
        Done = s.Done,
        Failed = s.Failed,
        LastStatus = js.Status
    };

var statistics = finalQuery.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you can see in the Sample data in my question  that there are 2 entries for Process id 100 with “Done” and “Failed”. So which status will be considered according to your query? I am looking to consider the latest Status per process id.

Comment: I am trying to understand that where in the query you are considering to select the top 1 process id per process group order by ProcessingTime

Comment: I can rewrite query. When i understand task. You have mentioned count of statuses. If you need just last status info then you need just 1 or 0 for appropriate fields.

Comment: Let’s say I have 1 more record for  Process Id = 100 with “Failed” status and ProcessedTime = 2022-11-10 19:41 then I don’t want “Failed” count as 2. It should be 1 only

Comment: If I have a new process with Process Id = 102 with Failed status then the count for Failed as 2 because its a different process id

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped me achieve the desired output with a slight change.